# How to enter array elements into Mysql table? Java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

I am using the split() function to fill an array and I am trying to enter each element into a Mysql table. What is the best way to do this? How can I make the loop iterate until it reaches the end of the array? I was thinking I might need a scanner object that reads from the array which would allow me to use the .hasNext() function. Is there a better way than this?

```
String text = "This is my example text string";
String array[] = text.split(" ");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `text.split(" ")` returns `String[]` not `String`, but you can loop through the array like this:

```
String text = "This is my example text string";
String[] array = text.split(" ");
for (String item : array) {
  // do something with each item 
  // like build an SQL statement
}
```

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add the square brackets in my example array declaration! But thanks a lot. This was exactly what I needed!